# CSS: click-to-mutate div, with clickable buttons inside. :focus with tabindex, possibly?

Tags: css, click, focus, expand, tabindex

In search of: **CSS only**, or *comprehensible*, small jquery. I've already written out exactly what I want in CSS only, using ":focus" and "tabindex="1"".

Objective:
- Click on div = div expands. (note: heavy CSS changing of multiple elements)
- Expanded div has child buttons inside.
- Child buttons clickable.

This worked like a charm with ":focus" and "tabindex="1"", but clicking on an the link inside the div removes the focus, and reverses the div expansion. I thought this workaround worked. But nay.

Here is a JSfiddle of what I've created (This is for an archives page on a webcomics site.) I have left all the styling, so you may understand exactly what I'm intending:

https://jsfiddle.net/gvs291wf/1/

```css
.comicselector {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: .3s;
  margin: 0 auto 45px;
  display: flex;
}

.comicselector:hover {
  box-shadow: -5px 0px 20px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .4), 5px 0px 20px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .4);
}

.comicselector:focus {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  outline-width: 0;
  box-shadow: -30vw 0 0px 0px hsla(280, 0%, 10%, 0.5), 30vw 0 0px 0 hsla(280, 0%, 10%, 0.5);
  z-index: 101;
  cursor: default;
}

.comimg {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #840;
}

.comimgtitle {
  font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 15px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1);
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.comicselector:focus .comimgtitle {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.comimgauthor {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 15px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1);
  font-variant: small-caps;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.comicselector:focus .comimgauthor {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.cominfo {
  flex: 0;
  background: hsla(190, 50%, 45%, 1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .4s;
}

.comicselector:focus .cominfo {
  flex: 1;
}

.infochild {
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 0s;
}

.comicselector:focus .infochild {
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 110;
  transition: .5s;
}

.comictitle {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.comicselector:focus .comictitle {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 20px hsla(0, 0%, 35%, .4);
}

.comicselector:focus .comicauthor {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-indent: 0.2em;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.comicselector:focus .startbeg {
  width: 42%;
  min-height: 70px;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 35%, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-indent: 0.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15% auto 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.comicselector:focus .startbeg:hover {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 12px hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 0.6);
  box-shadow: -230px 0 0px 0px hsla(280, 0%, 10%, 0.1), 230px 0 0px 0 hsla(280, 0%, 10%, 0.1), 0px 0px 24px 6px hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.1);
  background: hsla(0, 60%, 50%, 1);
}

.comicselector:focus .startlatest {
  width: 42%;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: hsla(260, 0%, 35%, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 1% auto 8%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.comicselector:focus .startlatest:hover {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 12px hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 0.6);
  box-shadow: -230px 0 0px 0px hsla(280, 0%, 10%, 0.1), 230px 0 0px 0 hsla(280, 0%, 10%, 0.1), 0px 0px 24px 6px hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.1);
  background: hsla(260, 60%, 50%, 1);
}

.seriesinfo {
  font-size: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.comicselector:focus .seriesinfo {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  background: hsla(260, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
}

.comicselector:focus .eachseriesnav {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 10%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background: hsla(260, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.comicselector:focus .chapnavlinks {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: hsla(260, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: 0s;
}

.comicselector:focus .chapnavlinks:hover {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 12px hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.6);
  background: hsla(260, 50%, 45%, 1);
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="comicselector" tabindex="1">
  <div class="comimg">
    <div class="comimgtitle">Title</div>
    <div class="comimgauthor">Author</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cominfo">
    <div class="comictitle infochild">title2</div>
    <div class="comicauthor infochild">author2</div>
    <a href="#" class="startbeg infochild">Start</a>
    <a href="#" class="startlatest infochild">Latest Release</a>
    <div class="seriesinfo infochild">comicdescrip
    </div>
    <div class="eachseriesnav infochild">
      <a href="" class="chapnavlinks">Chapter 1,2,etc</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: When do you want `.comicselector` to shrink back? Do you have several `.comicselector` items?

Comment: Yes, there are 10 comic series, each with this class. I figured people could just click outside of the expanded-div to srink it back, or just leave it and scroll to the next one.

Comment: Can more than one be open at the same time?

Comment: The links should do something in the same page or do they open another html page?

Comment: The links are links to separate pages. Nothing is special other than expanding the parent div with a click. I imagine the expanded version could be fixed on the page normally, but I want it to be collapsed into a smaller banner div.

Comment: If the links are to separate pages, the current page will be replaced while the div loses focus - ie you don't actually have a problem.

Comment: That's what I want, but I can't get it to work. When a link is clicked, focus is lost first. Please check the JSfiddle, which replicates the problem I'm having. I've considered making the child links somehow be separate, but z-index and positioning doesn't seem to do it (and I can't think of another way).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146307/discussion-between-plccory-and-ori-drori).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this should do what you intended. For each `.comicselector` there is a `<label>` that controls a hidden radio button. When the radio button is `:checked` the respective `.comicselector` has the behavior you want for the `:focus`. Since all radio buttons belong to the same group via the name attribute, checking one unchecks the current selected one.

When a radio is checked we hide the corresponding label (`display: none`), to prevent the `.comicselector` from closing by clicking it.

I've also added a background label to enable closing the selected `.comicselector` from outside.

**watch the snippet in the full page mode**

```css
.bg__label {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.comicselector {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: .3s;
  margin: 0 auto 45px;
  display: flex;
}

.comicselector:hover {
  box-shadow: -5px 0px 20px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .4), 5px 0px 20px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .4);
}

.comicselector__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.check {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.check:checked+.comicselector>.comicselector__overlay {
  display: none;
}

.check:checked+.comicselector {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  outline-width: 0;
  box-shadow: -30vw 0 0px 0px hsla(280, 0%, 10%, 0.5), 30vw 0 0px 0 hsla(280, 0%, 10%, 0.5);
  z-index: 101;
  cursor: default;
}

.comimg {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #840;
}

.comimgtitle {
  font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 15px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1);
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.check:checked+.comicselector .comimgtitle {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.comimgauthor {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 15px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1);
  font-variant: small-caps;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.check:checked+.comicselector .comimgauthor {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.cominfo {
  flex: 0;
  background: hsla(190, 50%, 45%, 1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .4s;
}

.check:checked+.comicselector .cominfo {
  flex: 1;
}

.infochild {
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 0s;
}

.check:checked+.comicselector .infochild {
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 110;
  transition: .5s;
}

.comictitle {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.check:checked+.comicselector .comictitle {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 20px hsla(0, 0%, 35%, .4);
}

.check:checked+.comicselector .comicauthor {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-indent: 0.2em;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.check:checked+.comicselector .startbeg {
  width: 42%;
  min-height: 70px;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 35%, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-indent: 0.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15% auto 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.check:checked+.comicselector .startbeg:hover {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 12px hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 0.6);
  box-shadow: -230px 0 0px 0px hsla(280, 0%, 10%, 0.1), 230px 0 0px 0 hsla(280, 0%, 10%, 0.1), 0px 0px 24px 6px hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.1);
  background: hsla(0, 60%, 50%, 1);
}

.check:checked+.comicselector .startlatest {
  width: 42%;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: hsla(260, 0%, 35%, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 1% auto 8%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.check:checked+.comicselector .startlatest:hover {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 12px hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 0.6);
  box-shadow: -230px 0 0px 0px hsla(280, 0%, 10%, 0.1), 230px 0 0px 0 hsla(280, 0%, 10%, 0.1), 0px 0px 24px 6px hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.1);
  background: hsla(260, 60%, 50%, 1);
}

.seriesinfo {
  font-size: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.check:checked+.comicselector .seriesinfo {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  background: hsla(260, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
}

.check:checked+.comicselector .eachseriesnav {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 10%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background: hsla(260, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.check:checked+.comicselector .chapnavlinks {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: hsla(260, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: 0s;
}

.check:checked+.comicselector .chapnavlinks:hover {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 12px hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.6);
  background: hsla(260, 50%, 45%, 1);
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<input id="check0" type="radio" name="control" class="check" />
<label for="check0" class="bg__label"></label>

<input id="check1" type="radio" name="control" class="check" />
<div class="comicselector" tabindex="1">
  <label for="check1" class="comicselector__overlay"></label>
  <div class="comimg">
    <div class="comimgtitle">Title</div>
    <div class="comimgauthor">Author</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cominfo">
    <div class="comictitle infochild">title2</div>
    <div class="comicauthor infochild">author2</div>
    <a href="#" class="startbeg infochild">Start</a>
    <a href="#" class="startlatest infochild">Latest Release</a>
    <div class="seriesinfo infochild">comicdescrip
    </div>
    <div class="eachseriesnav infochild">
      <a href="" class="chapnavlinks">Chapter 1,2,etc</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<input id="check2" type="radio" name="control" class="check" />
<div class="comicselector" tabindex="1">
  <label for="check2" class="comicselector__overlay"></label>
  <div class="comimg">
    <div class="comimgtitle">Title</div>
    <div class="comimgauthor">Author</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cominfo">
    <div class="comictitle infochild">title2</div>
    <div class="comicauthor infochild">author2</div>
    <a href="#" class="startbeg infochild">Start</a>
    <a href="#" class="startlatest infochild">Latest Release</a>
    <div class="seriesinfo infochild">comicdescrip
    </div>
    <div class="eachseriesnav infochild">
      <a href="" class="chapnavlinks">Chapter 1,2,etc</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, hero. You've brought magic back into my life.

Comment: Welcome. I really liked the idea and design.

Comment: Thank you very much. One issue: nothing else on the page is interactive (other links), since bg_label covers everything. The only workaround I can get is if each of those elements have a z-index, then they can be moused on.

Comment: @PLCcory - indeed. That's a caveat I can't find a way around. It can't be the container of the selector, so it must have position: absolute or fixed. You can add multiple labels that will point to the check0 at different containers in your code.

Comment: An additional workaround, that's situational, is making bg_label absolute, giving it a width of 200% and height 110%, left-50%, top-5%... creating a bubble around each banner. I have nothing on the sides, so clicking anywhere to L/R works, and 5% above and bellow.